# Get child component form value in parent component's form submission?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, output

> Note: since the [problem is a little complex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44303935/2404470), the code is abstracted for readability

We have a `<child-component>` component template like this:

```
<select name="someName" #someID ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="someModel" (ngModelChange)="onChange(someID.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let a of list" [ngValue]="a.key">{{a.value}}</option>
</select>
```

And the `ts` file is with [output](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7RNNj8u13g) configuration:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: 'child-component.html',
  outputs: ['someChildEvent']
})

export class ChildComponent {
  someChildEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  onChange(value) {
    this.someChildEvent.emit(value);
  }
}
```

Which we're calling in a `<parent-component>` like this:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (submit)="submit(f)" >
<child-component (childEvent)="childData=$event"></child-component>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

with `.ts` like:

```
export class ParentComponent {
    childData;

    submit(f) {
        //How to access childData here?
    }
}
```

- Is it the correct implementation of the [output configuration](http://learnangular2.com/outputs/) in Angular 2?
- How do we access the value of the `select`'s `option` from `<child-component>` on `<parent-component>`'s `form` submit to `submit(f)` function?

Comment: `childEvent` needs to be `someChildEvent`

Comment: @echonax Absolutely correct, however how do we get the value of `<child-component>`'s `select` element inside the `submit(f)` function?

Comment: Do you mean like `onChange($event)` instead of `onChange(someID.value)`?

Comment: @echonax The value of `$event` is coming as `0` when `onChange($event)` is used instead of `onChange(someID.value) `

Comment: That may be because `[ngValue]="a.key"` so `a.key` is `0` I guess? It'll send the whole object with `[ngValue]="a"`

Comment: Just a suggestion, instead of using the `outputs` property in the @Component annotation, use the @Output annotation on the someChildEvent property like so: `@Output() someChildEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();`

Comment: @Martin Can you elaborate? Why is it good?

Comment: It will make your code more readable and maintainable. For instance, if you refactor the name of the `someChildEvent` property you won't need to update the string array in `outputs` that can't be type-checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<child-component (childEvent)="childData=$event"></child-component>
```

the event name in here needs to match your method name so it should be:

```
<child-component (someChildEvent)="childData=$event"></child-component>
```

and if you like to send the object selected in your select box, change `ngValue` to that object and the change the model event accordingly:

`[ngValue]="a"`

`(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"`

Comment: @xameeramir Glad I could help :-)