# Unable to get hold of child DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

> Note: since the problem is a little complex, the code is abstracted for readability

We've a `<parent-component>` like this:

```
<child-component></child-component>
<button (click)="doSomeClick()"> Do Some Click </button>
```

The `template` of the `<child-component>` is:

```
<textarea #childComponentElement #someField="ngModel" name="someName" [(ngModel)]="someModel"></textarea>
```

We're trying to access the value of this element inside the `parent-component.component.ts` like this:

```
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('childComponentElement') el:ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.el.nativeElement.value);
    }
    doSomeClick(){

    }
}
```

However it throws this error:

> Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

What have we tried so far:

- [This gives access to `<parent-component>`, we need `<textarea>` of `<child-component>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43712884/2404470)
- [It's not about `angular-tree-component`](https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/issues/69#issuecomment-253432456)
- [The directive name is camelCased](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39158938/2404470)
- [`ElementRef` seems to be an old thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32693892/2404470)
- [This throws **Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35209681/2404470)
- [How is the reference between `this.element.nativeElement` & `<input>` element is getting established?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32709672/2404470)
- [There is no *ngIf or *ngSwitchCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41371577/2404470)
- [There is no `*ngIf` used with `#childComponentElement`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/411#issuecomment-233113374)
- [The call is inside `ngAfterViewInit` only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39094043/2404470)
- [Time out is a very dirty approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43384002/2404470)

Comment: have you tried the method from here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview ?

Comment: @Edwin `ngAfterViewInit` is correct in this usage. It's just that he's trying to access the templateRef from a parent component that the template does not belong to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no easy way to this with a nested component, you'll have to create an `EventEmitter` that emits the `ElementRef` of the element you are trying to get access to:

child.component.ts

```
class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @Output()
    templateLoaded: EventEmitter<ElementRef> = new EventEmitter()

    @ViewChild('childComponentElement') el: ElementRef

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.templateLoaded.emit(this.el)
    }
}
```

*parent.component.html*

```
<child-component (templateLoaded)="templateLoaded($event)"
```

*parent.component.ts*

```
class ParentComponent {

    templateLoaded(template: ElementRef): void {
        // do stuff with the `template`
    }
}
```

**Original Answer**

Try using the `read` property in the 2nd parameter of `ViewChild`

```
@ViewChild('childComponentElement', {read: ElementRef}) el: ElementRef
```

If you are wondering about the second parameter, this answer gives a very good explanation: [What is the read parameter in @ViewChild for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450805/what-is-the-read-parameter-in-viewchild-for)

Comment: After using the `read` property, the `this.el` is still undefined.

Comment: @xameeramir Ahh, are you trying to access the `ElementRef` from the parent component which does not have that html as the template?

Comment: Yes, we're accessing `<textarea>` of `<child-component>` from `parent-component.component.ts`

Comment: How do I I trigger `templateLoaded` inside `ParentComponent` to do the verification? When I reload the page, it doesn't hits into it neither by `console.log` or `debugger`

Comment: @xameeramir the `templateLoaded` function will be triggered by the event binding on the `child-component` element: `<child-component (templateLoaded)="templateLoaded($event)"...`. Were `$event` is actually the `ElementRef` emitted by the `ChildComponent`. You can't manually trigger it, if you must, you save the `template` variable inside a property of the `ParentComponent` and do the verification after wards, you can try the `ngAfterViewChecked` hook in the Parent

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@Output` decorator or a service instead of trying hopelessly to access the textarea directly from the parent component

child template

```
<textarea #childComponentElement #someField="ngModel" name="someName" [(ngModel)]="someModel"></textarea>
```

child component

```
@ViewChild('childComponentElement') el:ElementRef;
@Output() textarea = new EventEmitter();
constructor(){
this.textarea.emit(this.el.nativeElement.value);
}
```

parent template

```
<child-component (change)="getdata($event)"></child-component>
```

parent component

```
export class ParentComponent {
    getdata(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```